# Changing header Background on mobile Devices

Tags: jquery

i am trying to change the background color of the header section on a website when scrolling down. It works but for whatever reason it is not workin on the mobile view at all. Maybe i am just dumb but I hope someone is kind enough to help me out...

The script is the following:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) {
                jQuery(".pa-header").addClass("pa-fixed-header");
            } else {
                jQuery(".pa-header").removeClass("pa-fixed-header");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The css is just different colors for each class.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with that. Can you show us the page online ?

Comment: right now you wont see anything on the website since i totaly deactivated the mobile menu just because it looks terrible with a transparent header that is not changing its color...

Comment: But since the code you posted isn't wrong, there is something about your layout or CSS that's not working. Provide a working example where you reproduce the problem, and it will be easier to help you. [This code works](https://jsbin.com/rowoceruqi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output).

Comment: fixed it by just adding display:flex to the css...